# How to connect REACT-NATIVE with whisper ethereum protocol using GETH or any light Client or API

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, whisper

is there any thing connect to whisper(`web3.shh`) protocol in react-native.
How to connect REACT-NATIVE with whisper ethereum protocol using GETH or any light Client or API

Answer (score 1):

1. Add web3js to react-native:

   `yarn add web3@1.0.0-beta.34`

1.0.0-beta.34 works well in react-native environment for me. I wasnt very lucky with newer versions.

2. Run `./geth --rpcapi shh --shh` parameter to turn Whisper on.
3. Use something like this in your class:

```
this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:8546'));
...

let postData = {
            ttl: 2000,
            topic: defaultTopic,
            powTarget: 0.2,
            powTime: 20,
            payload: encodeToHex(JSON.stringify({
                _id: this.state.username,
                text: messages[0].text,
                name: this.state.username,
            })),
            symKeyID: some symKey,
            sig: some asymKeyId,
        };

this.web3.shh.post(postData);

let options = {
            topics: [defaultTopic],
            symKeyID: some symKey
        };
this.web3.shh.subscribe('messages', options)
                    .on('data', (message) => { ...
```